# How to make a grouped boxplot using 2 columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a boxplot as follows:
on the x axis: the different groups (Healthy, Disease1, Disease2)
on the y axis: the brain size , showing 'left brain size' and 'right brain size' side by side in different colors

I am using the ggplot function

```
data <- df[c("Group", "Left brain size", "Right brain size")]

ggplot(data, aes(x=Group ,y=..))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

How should I organize my data to have : x = Group , y = brain size , fill = side ?

Thank you!
PS: An example of my data is in the following table

| Group | Left brain size | Right brain size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Healthy | 0.5 | 0.9 |
| Healthy | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| Healthy | 0.8 | 0.4 |
| Disease 1 | 0.7 | 0.5 |
| Disease 1 | 0.9 | 0.3 |
| Disease 1 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| Disease 2 | 0.3 | 0.8 |
| Disease 2 | 0.4 | 0.54 |
| Disease 2 | 0.1 | 0.4 |
| Disease 2 | 0.3 | 0.2 |

Comment: Hi, you could reshape your data to get a colum "brain size" using, for ex, `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. It shoul look like: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = c("Left brain size", "Right brain size"), names_to = "side", values_to = "size")`

Comment: And then, use this new df like this: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Group, y = size, fill = side)) + geom_...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data to plot in R using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250872/reshaping-data-to-plot-in-r-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df_ %>% 
  rename( # here we rename the columns so things look nice in the graph later
    Left = Left.brain.size,
    Right = Right.brain.size
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer( # then we collapse the columns for each side of the brain into a single column, with a second column holding size values
    cols = c("Left", "Right"),
    names_to = "Side",
    values_to = "Size"
  ) %>% # then we plot and give it a title
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = Group,
      y = Size,
      fill = Side
    )
  ) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Hemisphere Size by Group"
  )
```

Here is the output:

[image: Box and whisker plot]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted ! It works perfectly. Thank you ! 

PS: I also wanted to add error bars using stat_boxplot, so I had to change the position of the error bars to match the boxes , this is what I did : 

  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = .75))

Thank you again !